# How to put a new line with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<b>Msg:</b> "+ msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

When I get the messages back they all come bunched up together. How can I put each message on a separate line?

Comment: Add `<br />` tags where necessary?  Or any other HTML formatting?  It's not clear what the values are that you're receiving, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: You should read up on HTML and CSS. Your question has nothing to do with Ajax.

Comment: ok but when i display my messages back in the div such as <div id="msgs" /> I am not sure where to put the breaks

Comment: @user3195165, are you asking where to put them as in where in the Javascript code? `document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<b>Msg:</b> "+ msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/>";` should do it. You just need to add the `"<br/>"` every time you add to the message.

Comment: the messages in html appear here <div id="msg" style="width:600px;height:600px;overflow:auto">
</div>

Comment: Then after executing the line of code in my previous comment, it should look like `<div id="msg" style="width:600px;height:600px;overflow:auto"><b>Msg:</b> This is the message<br/></div>` And if you execute it again with another message, it will be `<div id="msg" style="width:600px;height:600px;overflow:auto"><b>Msg:</b> This is the message<br/><b>Msg:</b> This is the second message<br/></div>` and so on

Comment: The messages are pulled from the xml ajax call though and display within the div, I don't hand code them in the div

Comment: Can you post the entire function that gets the xml and puts it in the div?

Comment: if(xhr) {
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
     var value = xhr.responseXML;
     var msgs = value.getElementsByTagName('message');
     console.log("Processing ", msgs.length, "messages");
     for(var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
      var id = parseInt(msgs[i].getAttribute("id"));
      if(lastid < id) {
       lastid = id;
      }
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<b>Message:</b> "+ msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
     
      
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a line break after each message in the div, you need to add a `<br/>` after each line that you add in your function. This can be achieved by attaching it to the end of the line you're adding. In this case,

```
"<b>Message:</b> " + msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

will look like

```
"<b>Message:</b> " + msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/>";
```

Now when the `innerHTML` of the div is changed, it will have a line break after it.

The whole function will look like this:

```
if(xhr) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                var value = xhr.responseXML;
                var msgs = value.getElementsByTagName('message');
                console.log("Processing ", msgs.length, "messages");

                for(var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    var id = parseInt(msgs[i].getAttribute("id"));
                    if(lastid < id) {
                        lastid = id;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<b>Message:</b> "
                        + msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue
                        + "<br/>" // NOTICE THE BR TAG BEING ADDED
                        + "\n";   // Added an actual newline for human readability
                                  // in case you want to log/alert the actual html
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will add to the div lines of html in the form of

```
<b>Message:</b> message 1<br/>
<b>Message:</b> message 2<br/>
<b>Message:</b> message 3<br/>
...
```

which will render in the browser like this

**Message:** message 1
**Message:** message 2
**Message:** message 3
...

Answer (score 3):

A newline in HTML is achieved by using `<br />` or putting content inside `<p>` tags.

Comment: Well, putting them into any block element (like `<p>`) will visually achieve a "newline".

Comment: Wherever you want there to be a new line

Comment: @Kapa, sure, but I think `<p>` is more valid than `<div>` or `<section>` in this case, for example

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie If the OP worried about semantic validity a bit, he would use something like a `<dl>`, but certainly not a `<b>`. Anyways, using a `<p>` *to achieve a newline* is incorrect. The OP should try to understand what HTML is and not think in terms of visual formatting (for which CSS is used).